# Local variable math displaying strange behavior

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a query to tell me the percentages of males and females in a data set (an expansion of a question I asked earlier).  Query is from only one table.

```
declare @totalPop int;
declare @totalmales int;
declare @totalFemales int;
declare @percentMales float;
declare @percentFemales float;
set @totalpop =(select count(*) from myTable)
set @totalmales =(select count(*) from myTable where (sex='m'))
set @totalfemales =(select count(*) from myTable where (sex='f'))
set @percentMales=@totalMales/totalPop
set @percenFemales =@totalFemales/totalPop

select sex, count(sex), @totalPop, @totalMales, @totalFemales
```

I know that currently this won't work, but I don't know how to divide by totalMales on one row and by totalFemales on the next

Comment: Is it that last `SELECT` you are wondering  about?

Comment: that is correct.  i'm new to sql and since the query ran i guess the rest is ok :)

Comment: What is the result you expect to see from the query? What value is "sex" (the first column) supposed to have? Are you expecting two rows, with the counts repeated on each row?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT Sex,
   @totalpop as 'TotalPopulation',
   CASE Sex
        WHEN 'm' THEN @TotalMales
        WHEN 'f' then @TotalFemales
        ELSE 'WTF?' END
   as 'SexCount'
   ...
FROM 
   MYTable
```

You can use a `CASE` to pick which number you show depending on the `sex` value.

Comment: lol @ else wtf :).  I didn't know that you could use logical expressions to define variables in SQL like this.  nifty stuff.

Comment: I tried to run this and ran into the same problem as I did before: the query will run but has 0 where the @percentMale/@percentFemale should be.

Comment: Well you aren't defining the variable here.  You may need to clarify what you want if you want to define it this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(id NUMBER, sex CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(1, 'm');
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(2, 'm');
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(3, 'f');
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(4, 'f');
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(5, 'f');

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sex) AS count_distinct_sex
      ,COUNT(*) AS totalPop
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'm' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalMales
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'f' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFemales
  FROM myTable;

COUNT_DISTINCT_SEX TOTALPOP TOTALMALES TOTALFEMALES
------------------ -------- ---------- ------------
                 2        5          2            3
```